# Zend_Http_Client not storing cookies

Tags: php, zend-framework, http, cookies, zend-http-client

I am using the following code to access a page protected by username/password login.

```
  //Fetch homepage
  $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
  $client->setCookieJar();
  $client->setUri('https://www.yourloungelearning.co.uk/crew_trainer/login.php');
  //$client->setParameterPost( 'username', $_SESSION['username'] );
  //$client->setParameterPost( 'password', $_SESSION['password'] );
  $client->setParameterPost( 'username', '#####' );
  $client->setParameterPost( 'password', '#####' );
  $response = $client->request('POST');

  // Now we're logged in, get private area! 
  $client->setUri('https://www.yourloungelearning.co.uk/crew_trainer/index.php');
  $response = $client->request('GET');

  echo $response->getBody();
```

The echo at the end always returns the login screen again (suggesting an unsuccessful login). This is copied almost exactly from the Zend docs. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you submit data for every field in the form. You're missing the submit button. You could also check the response from the login request (POST).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick couple of tests on that page reveal that you do indeed need to include the submit button value (the actual value is irrelevant, it just has to be present) as part of the POST data for the login to be processed.

```
$client->setParameterPost('submit', 'Login');
```

You would have noticed this if you checked the response from the login attempt.

Comment: Out of interest, what response are you talking about? The only response I had was the login page being sent again (instead of the user's home screen as I was expecting). There was no error that I could see =S

Comment: @gsteinert The response from the POST request. If you saw the form again, that means it hadn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday, look at the [API site](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/Zend_Http/Client/Zend_Http_Client.html#setCookieJar).

```
->setCookieJar(true)
```

The parameter true constructs a new CookieJar, without this parameter it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but: Instead of using just `->setCookieJar()`, you should manually instantiate a `Zend_Http_CookieJar` and pass that. This way you can debug more easily if you've actually received a login cookie.

Comment: Helpful for adding watches but you can always get at the cookie jar created by `setCookieJar`